# Where is Jarrik The Crusher's loot kept?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

In Skyrim Falskaar, where is Jarrik the Crusher's loot kept? There is no quest arrow. I got a key from Jarrik's corpse, just can not find his loot chest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one room with many bed's in the Mammoths Keep. Look from one mudcrab in the wall, have on chest down of there.